# Show dailymotion video and thumbnail in correct 16:9 format

Tags: php, dailymotion-api

If any one knows how to get the thumbnails in correct 16:9 format from dailymotion API please let me know. I tried with https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?fields=id,thumbnail_360_url,title&thumbnail_ratio=widescreen but still not getting how to get 16:9 format. For Example : http://s2.dmcdn.net/HHNat/320x240-8jE.jpg is giving 4:3 format. But in the same way how can I get 16:9 format thumbnail?

Comment: I got it. Use https://api.dailymotion.com/video/VIDEO_ID?fields=thumbnail_360_url. For EX : https://api.dailymotion.com/video/x25gmt5_family-and-celebrities-say-goodbye-to-joan-rivers-at-funeral_news?fields=thumbnail_360_url will give you url for 16:9 image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to reply to this question since the answer is in your question.
The [`thumbnail_ratio`](http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/obj-video.html#global-api-parameters) global API parameter controls the aspect of the thumbnails returned by the API. As of today, it accepts either `original` (default), `widescreen` or `square`. If you don't provide this parameter, you cannot control the aspect ratio of the thumbnail, it will always depend on the video. So the correct call was in your question all along:
`https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?fields=thumbnail_360_url&thumbnail_ratio=widescreen`

Comment: Thanks for the point to point answer. As I am new to Dailymotion so I did not know how to pass parameter to get the result.